# google line-chart api for haxis for date

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I am having a list of data update daily based.

```
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Calorie');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2012,7,1),  400],
      [new Date(2012,7,2),  460],
```

the date will increase for 3 months is there any way for me to display only 1st day of the month in the haxis.

```
                        hAxis: {
                        gridlines:{count:3, color: 'white'},
                        minValue: new Date(2012, 1, 31),
                        maxValue: new Date(2012, 9, 30),
                        showTextEvery:30,
            format:'d-MMM',
                    },
```

that is my current haxis api code. it somehow display only 1-Aug.

Comment: The hAxis, for reasons beyond my comprehension, doesn't like taking minValue/maxValue arguments too much. Yes, this is silly. You can cheat the system a bit by using a dummy series as I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194013/google-chart-how-to-draw-the-vertical-axis-for-linechart/14274651#14274651) but that won't solve your entire problem... It may give you some hints on what to try though!

Answer (score 2):

To get the result as your wish comment the showTextEvery property in options object.

```
hAxis: {
    gridlines:{count:3, color: 'white'},
    minValue: new Date(2012, 1, 31),
    maxValue: new Date(2012, 9, 30),
    // showTextEvery:30,
    format:'d-MMM'
}
```

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/category/google-charts/) site,it has Google charts related faqs. It may be helpful to you.